# Circuit schematic in Eagle seems to connected in series in board layout

Tags: eaglecad, circuit-design

I am very new to Eagle. I was drawing a schematic that would connect my AVR Dragon to my Atmega32A. I drew this up and switched to board layout. [image]

The problem is in board layout. It seems to me that VCC is connected in series from the square pad -> 10k resistor, pin30 -> pin10, C1 (0.1uf) -> C2 (0.1uF) The square pad (for VCC) is outside the drawing board to the left. I was certain that these are supposed to be connected in parallel. I apologize if I am missing something here but I do not see any thing wrong with my schematic. Please correct me.[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about connecting things in series and parallel. Branches of a circuit can be in series or parallel. But individual pins aren't in series or in parallel. They're just connected to whatever they're connected to.

Comment: Please get rid of the angled wires. They make things more confusing and just look ugly. Stick to 90 degree wire angles in the schematic

Comment: Also, make sure the pad size you need/want is right. They look a little big for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the pins in your schematic that are connected to the same named net need to end up connected to each other in the layout. For example, the IC's pin 10, the mounting pad, and the one pin of the 10 kohm resistor need to all end up connected to each other.

The ratsnest lines (or whatever Eagle calls them) don't mean you have to connect from IC pin 10 to the pad to the resistor. If you connect from the IC directly to the resistor, Eagle will sort it out and remove one ratsnest line. And probably re-adjust the remaining one to be as short as possible and still indicate the required connection.

Comment: "For example, the IC's pin 10, the mounting pad, and the one pin of the 10 kohm resistor need to all end up connected to each other" If this is the case then aren't they connected in series? Does this mean my circuit schematic is okay?

Comment: No, they aren't in series. Current from the IC doesn't have to go through the resistor to get to the pad, for example.

Comment: But it looks like it does from the board layout. Oh man I am so confused

Comment: How so? The IC pin 10 has a direct connection to the pad, and a direct connection to the resistor.  The other end of the resistor is connected to different stuff.

Comment: The direct connection must mean that the voltage is divided among pin 10 and the resistor right? Shouldn't the line connecting pin 10 and the pad have one more branch connecting to pin30?

Comment: No, it means the voltage is the same at those 3 pins. You should not think of pins being in parallel or series with each other. Devices can be in series. Devices can be in parallel. Pins are just a way to connect a device to a track or other copper on the board.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. I feel so stupid. Thank you so much for dealing with my ineptitude.

Comment: Next time put designators on your test pads, it probably would have made things more clear.

Comment: The airlines or ratsnest lines (or whatever Eagle calls them) just indicate all the points that should be connected together, but don't imply that the PCB tracks should necessarily follow the airline paths.  I use the airlines only as a rough guide for PCB routing, not as any sort of definite requirement for track placement.  (But when I'm finished, all the airlines should have vanished).

Answer (score 1):

The square pad outside the drawing is NOT VCC, it is reset! VCC is the pad at the bottom of the drawing!Ground is the left hand pad of that cluster of three at the top...